# Python pandas.datetimeindex piecewise dataframe slicing

Tags: python, dataframe, slice

I have a dataframe with a pandas DatetimeIndex. I need to take many slices from it(for printing a piecewise graph with matplotlib). In other words I need a new DF which would be a subset of the first one.
More precisely I need to take all rows that are between 9 and 16 o'clock but only if they are within a date range. Fortunately I have only one date range and one time range to apply.

What would be a clean way to do that? thanks

Comment: This is one of the things I tried. It apparently can't extract date and time from the index in any way:  
`ax1.plot(myDF[(myDF.index.date >= view_start_date) &  
(myDF.index.date <= view_end_date) &  
(myDF.index.time >= start_time) &  
(myDF.index.time <= end_time)]["my_column"].index,  
myDF[(myDF.index.date >= view_start_date) &  
(myDF.index.date <= view_end_date) &  
(myDF.index.time >= start_time) &  
(myDF.index.time <= end_time)]["my_column"],  
color="b", label="Hello")`

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to set the index of the dataframe to the column where you store time. Once the index is based on time, you can subset the dataframe easily.

```
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], format='%H:%M:%S.%f') # assuming you have a col called 'time' 
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S.%f')
df.set_index('time', inplace=True)
new_df = df[startTime:endTime] # startTime and endTime are strings
```

Comment: ok, I don't actually have date or time objects in the dataframe columns, but only in the index as (DatetimeIndex obj). There is no way that you know to extract date or time from the index withing a boolean filtering? The program is somewhat resource intensive and I would like to avoid generating new columns or dataframes. I can suppose these are resource intensive for big dataframes. It would be preferable to filter directly in the index I think. Thanks